# Chrome extension data connection to server

Tags: database, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to connect my Chrome Extension to my server, and send data back and forth. In particular, when the user clicks a button on the extension when he's navigating a certain URL, the server checks its database to see how many times that URL has been clicked, increment the count, and send the new count back to the user.

I know that sending the data to the server is possible with an AJAX request, but what about getting the data back from the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you may use AJAX for getting updated count in a straightforward manner. For example (with jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/count.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(newURL),
  // dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    // parse you data received from server here
    // data.count
  }
});
```

So you can "send" new info as parameters of GET request, and get required information from server as http-response. The type of the data used to transfer the count is up to you. For example, this can be `json` (jQuery provides a shorthand method `getJSON`, which does the same customized `ajax` call).

If you don't want GET, you may use POST and specify data as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax/count.php",
  data: { url: newURL },
  success: function(data){
    // ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will obviously need to use **xhr** / **ajax**

But with the present chrome-extension API you might get an error like this

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In order to get around this problem one can simply put the link to the server on the permission array in manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://www.myserver.dom"
],
```

For more detailed description see [this documentation by Google](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

Comment: That, or if it's a server you control - you can add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.